# App not compatible with buildpack - django project with java script

Tags: javascript, django, heroku, buildpack

When I try to deploy my app to Heroku then I received:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. heroku/python
       2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

I've been trying to spend a lot of time. Most of the solution is not working. Is it a buildpack issue or something else?
Additionally, I connected my GitHub account to Heroku and tried deploying from the GitHub main branch. However, I still receive the error. Here is my GitHub address: https://github.com/Whitemoon2000/Final-year-project

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the static buildpack? That isn't normally needed for a Django deployment, and I'm not sure that it makes sense to use a buildpack for hosting static content alongside one for Python.

In any case, when using multiple buildpacks the [main buildpack must be declared last](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app#adding-a-buildpack):

> The buildpack for the **primary language** of your app should always be the **last** buildpack in the list. This ensures that defaults for that primary language are applied instead of those for another language, and allows Heroku to correctly detect the primary language of your app.

If you don't actually have a reason to use the static buildpack, you should be able to [clear your configured buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-buildpacks-clear) and let Heroku detect the right one:

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
```

The presence of a `requirements.txt`, `Pipfile`, or `setup.py` file in the root directory of your project will [identify it as a Python project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#recognizing-a-python-app).

If you do need that buildpack (or any other) in addition to `heroku/python`, reorder them, e.g.

```sh
heroku buildpacks:remove https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/static  # shorter name
```

You can verify that the list is correct with [`heroku buildpacks`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-buildpacks).

Note that the static buildpack [requires a `static.json` file](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#deploying). Without that, you'll still get the "app not compatible with buildpack" error.